# The 'UmbracoCms.Core 7.6.5' package requires NuGet client version '3.4.4' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.8.1.0'

Tags: nuget, umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco-cloud

### Intro

I am trying to create a project from the cloud using "UaaS.cmd".

I run it, fill the url and namespace and it start working. Then in the middle of the process I get the error:

```
Installing UmbracoCms.Core
 The 'UmbracoCms.Core 7.6.5' package requires NuGet client version '3.4.4' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.8.1.0'.
    at NuGet.PackageWalker.CheckPackageMinClientVersion(IPackage package)
    at NuGet.PackageWalker.Walk(IPackage package)
    at NuGet.InstallWalker.ResolveOperations(IPackage package)
    at NuGet.ProjectManager.Execute(IPackage package, IPackageOperationResolver resolver)
    at Waasp.PackageInstaller.InstallPackage(String packageId, SemanticVersion version, String projectPath, String targetFolder)
```

But I have VS 2015 and VS 2017 installed. My Vs 2015 says that I have nuget version 3.5 installed and vs 2017 says that I have nuget v4.2.

### What have I tried

I ran nuget in my cmd, but it was not a recognized so I've downloaded the latest version and have added it to my environment, so when I run cmd, go to the folder where I have my uaas.cmd file and type

> nuget update -self

It tells me that I have nuget 4.2 and it is up to date. But when I try the uaas.cmd, the same error happens

I don't understand! where does it find 2.8.1.0?! why doesn't it take 4.2?

P.S: I also wrote on Umbraco forum, but I guess it is more related to the nuget client than umbraco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote my question on our Umbraco too and it appeared to be their error :)

### In case anyone ended up in the same situation as me:

This is the answer from Sebastiaan:
[link to the topic](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-cloud/87383-the-umbracocmscore-765-package-requires-nuget-client-version-344-or-above-but-the-current-nuget-version-is-2810)

```
The problem is that UaaS.cmd does run nuget 2.8.1 in it (it's ILmerged into the waasp.exe it download).

I'm working on getting it updated but the v4 version of nuget.exe is missing some critical methods that we need to create the list of dependencies. So I'm looking into doing some trickery. Anyway, for now, just go into the .Core project and install Newtonsoft.Json and System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow and then you should be fine!
```